# How to parse multiple, consecutive xml files in one document?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a big text file that is a sequence of XML-valid documents that looks something like this:

```
<DOC>
   <TEXT> ... </TEXT>
    ...
</DOC>
<DOC>
    <TEXT> ... </TEXT>
    ...
</DOC>
```

etc. There is no `<?xml version="1.0">`, the `<DOC></DOC>` delimits each separate xml. What's the best way to parse this in Java and get the values under `<TEXT>` in each `<DOC>`?

If I pass the whole thing to a DocumentBuilder, I get an error saying the document is not well formed. Is there a better solution than simply traversing through, a building a string for each `<DOC>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **valid** XML document must have a *root* element under which you can specify all other elements. Also, in a document only ONE *root* element can be present. have a look on [XML Specification (see point 2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-document)

So, to overcome your issue, you can take all the content of your text file into a String (or StringBuffer/StringBuilder...) And put this string in between `<root>` and `</root>` tags
e.g ,

```
String origXML = readContentFromTextFile(fileName);
String validXML = "<root>" + origXML + "</root>";
//parse validXML
```

Answer (score 2):

The document is not well formed because you don't have a 'root' node:

```
<ROOT>
    <DOC>
       <TEXT> ... </TEXT>
        ...
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <TEXT> ... </TEXT>
        ...
    </DOC>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a hard time parsing this with a "standard" XML parser such as Xerces. As you mentioned this XML document is not well-formed in part because it is missing an XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0"?>` but most importantly because it has two document roots (i.e. the `<doc>` elements).

I suggest you give [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) a try. It is intented to parse (quote) "poor, nasty and brutish" XML. No guarantee but that's probably your best shot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The site in that link no longer exists. 'TagSoup' turns up other links but hard to tell what's canonical.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using xslt for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass of InputStream that adds a prefix and a suffix to the input stream, and pass an instance of that class to any XML parser:

```
public class EnclosedInputStream extends InputStream {
    private enum State {
        PREFIX, STREAM, SUFFIX, EOF
    };

    private final byte[] prefix;
    private final InputStream stream;
    private final byte[] suffix;
    private State state = State.PREFIX;
    private int index;

    EnclosedInputStream(byte [] prefix, InputStream stream, byte[] suffix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (state == State.PREFIX) {
            if (index < prefix.length) {
                return prefix[index++] & 0xFF;
            }
            state = State.STREAM;
        }
        if (state == State.STREAM) {
            int r = stream.read();
            if (r >= 0) {
                return r;
            }
            state = State.SUFFIX;
            index = 0;
        }
        if (state == State.SUFFIX) {
            if (index < suffix.length) {
                return suffix[index++] & 0xFF;
            }
            state = State.EOF;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need InputStream as a parameter in a constructor? You can use super.read() instead of stream.read() (as EnclosedInputStream is a subclass of InputStream).

Comment: You do not necessarily have access to the code that creates the InputStream with the original content. Suppose you have an URL for instance.