# Add invalid xml elements to xml document java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom-2

I have the following code:

```
Document mainContent = new Document();
Element rootElement = new Element("html");
mainContent.setContent(rootElement);
Element headElement = new Element("head");
Element metaElement = new Element("meta");
metaElement.setAttribute("content", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
headElement.addContent(metaElement);
rootElement.addContent(headElement);
org.jdom2.output.Format format = org.jdom2.output.Format.getPrettyFormat().setOmitDeclaration(true);
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(format);
System.out.println(outputter.outputString(mainContent));
```

This will produce the output :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
</html>
```

Now, I have the following string:

```
String links = "<link src=\"mysrc1\" /><link src=\"mysrc2\" />"
```

How can I add it to the HTML element so the output will be:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <link src="mysrc1" />
       <link src="mysrc2" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Please note that it's NOT a valid XML element altogether, but each link is a valid XML Element.

I don't mind using another XML parser if needed. I am already using somewhere else in my code HTMLCleaner if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like they mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946064/how-to-parse-multiple-consecutive-xml-files-in-one-document). Basically place your xml snippet inside of a root element:

```
links ="<root>"+links+"</root>";
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=builder.parse(links ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
NodeList nl = ((Element)doc.getDocumentElement()).getChildNodes();
for (int temp = 0; temp < nl .getLength(); temp++) { 
Node nNode = nl .item(temp);
    //Here you create your new Element based on the Node nNode, and the add it to the new DOM you're building

}
```

Then parse links as a valid XML document, and extract the nodes you want (basically anything other than the root node)

Comment: What do you mean by extract the nodes that you want? it will remove the root as well